# Не понимаю, почему не вызывается конструктор копии

Tags: c++

В общем то все работает так как я задумал. Не обращайте внимания на наличие setlocale во всех функциях. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему при вызове операторной функции не вызывается конструктор копии. Может быть глупый вопрос, я занимаюсь всего 20 дней от силы
П.С среда code blocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

class cl
{
    char* p;
public:
    cl take();
    void output(){cout<<p;}
    void operator=(cl ob);
    void strcp(char* str);
    cl(char* str);
    cl(const cl& ob);
    ~cl(){delete p;cout<<"\nОбъект удален\n";}
};

cl cl::take()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    cl ob2(p);
    strcpy(ob2.p,p);
    p = 0;
    return ob2;
}

cl::cl(const cl& ob)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    p = new char [strlen(ob.p)];
    cout<<"\nКопия объекта создана!\n";
}

void cl::operator=(cl ob)
{
    p = new char [strlen(ob.p) + 1];
    strcpy(p,ob.p);
}

cl::cl(char* str)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    p = new char [strlen(str) + 1];
    cout<<"\nОбъект создан!\n";
}

inline void cl::strcp(char* str)
{
    strcpy(p,str);
}

int main()
{
    int len;
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    cout<<"Введите длину строки:\n";
    cin>>len;
    char str[len];
    while(cin.get() != '\n')
    {
        cin.clear();
    }
    cout<<"Введите строку:\n";
    gets(str);
    cout<<'\n'<<strlen(str)<<'\n';
    OemToCharA(str,str);
    cl ob(str);
    ob.strcp(str);
    ob = ob.take();
    cout<<"\nТут должен быть конструктор копии\n";
    ob.output();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с того, что оно у вас вообще-то не должно компилироваться - по стандарту:

```
char str[len];
```

`len` должно быть константой, а не переменной. `gets` забудьте сразу, как страшный сон! Категорически!

`setlocale` достаточно вызвать один раз, а не перед каждым выводом. Ну, это вы сами написали...

И последнее - отключите всю оптимизацию, и вы должны будете увидеть вызов копирующего конструктора. Просто оптимизатор достаточно умный, понимает, что можно обойтись и без конструктора, создавая возвращаемый объект прямо в переменной, без копирования (т.н. оптимизация RVO, стандартом разрешена).

По крайней мере, VC++ с `/Od` таки вызывает копирующий конструктор...

Comment: там много чего странно сделано, но я так понимаю это учебный пример....

Comment: В данном случае это будет NRVO